# Duda para cambiar datos de una img

Tags: html, html5, css, iframe

Con las muy buenas a la comunidad, tengo la siguiente duda, estoy trabajando en php y mysql. necesito cambiar una parte de un

```
<img src="http://localhost/upload/foto.jpg" width="259" height="194" />
```

quiero eliminar el ***width*** y el **height** del img, por que eso se manejara desde código css, para que sea responsive y se ajuste libremente en la página. Como cuando se crea un articulo nuevo a veces hay varias imagenes dentro del mismo articulo **$_POST['articulo']**, trate de hacerlo con explode pero no me resulta, y lo mismo me gustaria para realizar con los

si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria

```
<form method="POST">
<textarea name="articulo"></textarea>
</form>
```

por lo tanto todo lo que se escriba en el textarea estará bajo tinymce.

```
<?php
$articulo=$_POST['articulo'];
//reemplazo algunos caracteres
$articulo=str_replace('<img src="../..', '<img src="http://localhost/", $articulo);
```

ejemplo: el $articulo vendria con lo siguiente ->

```
<p>este es un articulo para mostrar <img src="localhost/upload/foto.jpg" width="259" height="194" /></p>
```

aca necesito hacer la eliminacion del witdh y height que viene en la etiquieta

Comment: No se entiende lo que realmente necesitas, intenta explicarte mejor para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: estoy haciendo una seccion de creación de articulos, que a traves de un boton me envia lo ingresado a taves de un $_POST; 
y cuando ingreso imagenes a traves de tinymce este editor por defecto ingresa los img con los datos de width y height, entonces yo al trabajar las img quiero eliminar ese width y height, trate con str_replace y con explode y no logre hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo quiere es solo quitar el **width** y  el **height** al prueba esto:

```
$cadena = '<p style="text-align: center;">esta es una imagen de prueba</p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="upload/foto.jpg" alt="ee" width="25" height="194" /></p><p style="text-align: center;"><img src="upload/foto2.jpg" alt="" width="2" height="194" /></p><p style="text-align: center;">y con esto termino</p>';
$patrón = '/((width="([0-9])+")|(height="([0-9])+"))/i';
$sustitución = '';
echo preg_replace($patrón, $sustitución, $cadena);
```

osea tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
<?php
$articulo=$_POST['articulo'];
//reemplazo algunos caracteres
$articulo=str_replace('<img src="../..', '<img src="http://localhost/", $articulo);
$patrón = '/((width="([0-9])+")|(height="([0-9])+"))/i';
$articulo = preg_replace($patrón, '' , $articulo);
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, eso era lo que necesitaba. Abrazos.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

La imagen debieras direccionarla desde donde esta almacenada, no desde la url del localhost, cambia src por:

```
<img src="/upload/foto.jpg"/>
```

No olvides que debes agregar la etiqueta para aplicar de manera responsiva los atributos que aplicaras en la imagen, en este caso tu css.

```
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; name="viewport">
```

Por ultimo en tu codigo css, si quieres que la imagen tome el 100% de la pantalla del dispositivo debes asignar la propiedad correspondiente:

**CSS**

```
img .upload {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

}